# I'm having trouble downloading files from command-line

Tags: windows, curl, command-line, download

When I'm trying to download [this file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au1rRwKhH5bjhTa3ajLVrhoJw9Ox?e=ljZURp) or the same file, [on MEGA](https://mega.nz/file/UBUk1Z7D#JVtRs9cINarPn9mvjpk8CWUKH-xIMzjSzRwq17u80os), the file which is transferred is 7Kb instead of the expected 2.2Mb.

[Command and file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzgoh.png).

This is the command I tried:

```bash
curl -o JavaSetup8u361.exe https://mega.nz/file/UBUk1Z7D#JVtRs9cINarPn9mvjpk8CWUKH-xIMzjSzRwq17u80os
```

Comment: Why would you need to download an installer from either of those locations when oracle.com should be the best place to do so?

Comment: Thats example file. I had same problems with other files.

Comment: Wow, so not only have you deliberately, and unnecessarily omitted the real file name and URI, you also provided the size for that made up file too! The exact site and file is important for us to diagnose the true method of retrieving it, please [Edit] your question to provide that information.

Comment: No, nothing here was changed. I have same problem with ~ 4 files. This is one of them. I belive that when i will find the solutionfor this one then downloading rest of files also will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case, some sites have restrictions and require different URI's and methodologies.

Comment: Ok, in that case i just want to download this file with console, any file more. And maybe if I will download this file correctly, then i will try downloading other files.

Comment: From which of the two completely different domains?

Comment: No, all files are .exe and from MEGA

Comment: Your question suggests otherwise, in fact it implies that the non MEGA link is the primary concern!

Comment: Oh wait I forgot about OneDrive. I dont think that thats cloud service problem, I tried a lot of them and still had same problem. MEGA and OneDrive are services that I most want to work.